# Install Godaddy ssl certificate on tomcat 8.5 Server

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, tomcat8

I am trying to install SSL certificate on my website.I am using **Godaddy ssl certificate** for this.
I have generated the csr, requested the Certificate and also uploaded the certificate on my server.

**I am using KEYTOOL to use all of these**

I got three file in the .zip file which i downloaded from godaddy. 
While installing the certificate. there are three command which i have to use to add the certificate to keystore.
They commands are for **Root , intermediate and Primary certificate**.

**How can i identify which certificate is root, intermediate and primary in zip.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is old post.  I just ran into the same issue.  According to GoDaddy, the random#.crt is root, the gd_bundle*.crt is intermediate, and lastly, the *.pem is the primary.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I Did the successfully on my tomcat server :)

Comment: man is this legit? some say (staff from godaddy) random#.crt is the primary bundle is root and pem is intermed? 
@ShyantanDeb did you solve it already?

Comment: Yes, I know this is late reply, I did it and running the site from last 2 years using godaddy SSL

Comment: @ShyantanDeb could you please provide a link to a blog or post which can explain the complete process of installing Godaddy SSL on tomcat 9 on Ubuntu OS. I have traversed many bolg but none of them explains perfectly. Please Help.

Comment: @AnkitSahu did you ever find a good blog post on this topic?