# Obtaining an SSL cert for a domain hosted zone in AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns

The title of the question is a mouthful, but I am trying to configure a Go Daddy SSL cert which I purchased for my domain on AWS.  I purchased the domain `myapp.com` (not the real name) from AWS, and then I configured `myapp.myapp.com` as a record set in Route 53 to point to an EC2 instance, which in turn is running the actual Tomcat server which I expect users would be hitting.  In other words, this is the site used to hit the app/website, and I have confirmed that it works and is reachable.

I purchased an SSL cert from Go Daddy for `myapp.myapp.com`.  I followed the instructions to import the root, intermediate, and issued certificates (3 in total) into my Java keystore.  Then, I configured my Tomcat `server.xml` to use this keystore.  I am not certain that I did this correctly, or in the correct order, if that matters.  In any case, when I try to hit the address

```
https://myapp.myapp.com:8443/
```

I get the following error on Chrome:

```
Your connection is not private
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I might be doing wrong here?  Go Daddy's customer support, while free, does not offer this level of tech support.  I could go with AWS, but they tend to charge enterprise rates.

An ideal answer would include, at least as an outline, the following steps:

1. How to import the Go Daddy certs into my Java keystone
2. How to configure Tomcat server.xml properly to use the keystore
3. Sanity checks along the way, which someone else with a similar problem would be able to use

Here are the three certs which Go Daddy returned to me:

```
c4c170b79c58acc3.crt  (root?)
gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt   (intermediate?)
gdig2.crt.pem         (primary/issued?)
```

I am not sure which of these certs are root, intermediate, and issued, but [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480882/install-godaddy-ssl-certificate-on-tomcat-8-5-server?rq=1) would label them as I have above.

Comment: Your next step should be to open the SSL certificate details in the browser and see exactly **why** it thinks the SSL certificate is invalid.

Comment: Do you have Apache in front of Tomcat?  While a little bit more complicated it means that Tomcat doesn't run as root and you don't have to go through the Java keystore dance.

Comment: Are there startup errors in tomcat logs? If  you can see the cert details in Chrome, as @MarkB suggested, your server is configured correctly and the problem might be with Chrome. For instance, it may decide your CA is not trustable.

Comment: Did you try it in another browser? I just had a cert warning in Chrome for no apparent reason, and it worked in Firefox.

Comment: @Tim, is this a spring boot app?

Comment: @stdunbar I do not have Apache in front of Tomcat to my knowledge unless this be the default setup in AWS.

Comment: @jingx I get the same error on Safari.  When I accept the untrusted cert there, then I can see the Tomcat default startup page.

Comment: @MarkB How can I open a cert in the browser?  I tried opening the issue certificate `.pem` file in Chrome, but it just appears as a downloaded item in the bottom task bar.

Comment: https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/how-to-view-ssl-certificate-details-in-chrome-56/

Comment: Note: I ended up dropping GoDaddy, because it has almost no technical support.  I switched to DigiCert, and everything worked from the very first try.  Slightly more expensive, but you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

To do this for a spring boot app do the following:

```
sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -out cs.pkcs12 -inkey /path/to/domain.key -in /path/to/domain.cer -certfile /path/to/domain.ca-bundle -name server -passout somestorepass

sudo keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore cs.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12  -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS  -srcstorepass somestorepass -deststorepass somestorepass
```

in `application.properties`

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=server
server.ssl.key-password=somestorepass
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

If you have tomcat, the first two commands stay the same, you just need to configure tomcat to to use the correct `alias` and the correct key store password.

Have a look at the [`Connector`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) configuration for tomcat to configure the alias, keystore password, keystore etc.

Edit: 
Would recommend that you delete the intermediate files (not the JKS) once done.

Comment: Can you give me a reference for the first two commands?  I don't recognize the second, and the first only looks vaguely familiar.

Comment: Also, are you aware that I am using a Go Daddy SSL cert, _not_ a self signed certificate?  I ultimately will be using Tomcat with an Android app, so the cert has to come from an authority.

Comment: Yes, typically CA's send out PEM encoded and the first command is convert PEM to PKCS, look at https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/pkcs12.html for details.

Comment: So you are saying that I can't just import the `.pem` file Go Daddy sends me, I need to use the `openssl` to first convert it?  What about the intermediate and root certs?  Do I need to convert those as well?  Thanks for you help, by the way.

Comment: The second command is the keytool import the pkcs file into a JKS store that tomcat can use. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, atleast that what I do, typically you should get a .cer file that is the public cert, a .key file that is the private key and a .ca-bundle that has all the intermediate and root certs. If you have them spearate, just concat all of them into a single file called teh ca-bundle and use that in the first command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170343/discussion-between-yogesh-d-and-tim-biegeleisen).